# Problem using doparallel and png together

Tags: r, png, doparallel, parallel-foreach

Using %dopar% in combination with png. For some reason R keeps being stuck when it sees this code. Would appreciate advice on what is the reason for it being stuck and how to work around it.

```
myCluster <- makeCluster(2, type = "FORK")
registerDoParallel(myCluster)

foreach(f = 1:2) %dopar% {
  png(filename = paste("test", f, ".png", sep = ""), width = 300, height = 300)
  plot(sin, -pi, f * pi)
  dev.off()
}

stopCluster(myCluster)
```

I'm using Mac with macOS Mojave if it's important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to remove `type = "FORK"` option in `makeCluster` function. This option is mainly used for Windows and Unix-alike platforms.

```
myCluster <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(myCluster)

foreach(f = 1:2) %dopar% {
  png(filename = paste("test", f, ".png", sep = ""), width = 300, height = 300)
  plot(sin, -pi, f * pi)
  dev.off()
}

stopCluster(myCluster)
```

more information right [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/parallel/versions/3.5.2/topics/makeCluster)

Comment: It actually works, but I don't understand why. I thought this option is used to inherit variables from main code the same way if you fork the process in Linux. What is the problem that happens here?

Comment: it  basically depends on OS. By default, macOS supports fork directly with `makeCluster`, while Windows not. Check this out: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf